# How can I make a polyurethane formulae more adhesive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, medicinal-chemistry

For a project I'm working on, how can I make polyurethane more adhesive and able to stick to surfaces more effectively, not necessarily super-glue like but just stickier properties. What other chemicals may I need to add, or would I need to also alter the main 2 ingredients? (isocyanate and polyol)

Also interested in making the formulae more medically stable, safe for skin and deeper wounds.

I would appreciate any input or answers!

Comment: Look at a chemical data safety sheet for the isocyanate of interest, e.g., https://www.amcsupplies.com.au/manuals/ISF%20136%20Isocyanate%20-%20MSDS.pdf, and decide if it's suitable for use as a wound adhesive. Certain words such as "carcinogen" and "toxic" might be good clues.

Comment: polyurethane has been used as a wound treatment method in recent experiments so it is safe for wounds, I was mainly looking for ways to make it more adhesive